# How can I get a label, info from php, to change when the value of the dropdown changes?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have been looking at this code for probably 4 hours now trying to get it to do what I want. I want it so that when a new value is put in the dropdown menu the label below will update, but the information is coming from PHP though. How would I do this cause I have looked everywhere and I can't find something that would help. I think I saw somewhere that I can't do it like this with PHP since it is processed server side not client side, if that is true can you tell me what I am supposed to do?

```
<?php
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
        function updatePrice()
        {
                var x = document.getElementById('partNumber').value;
                document.getElementById('price').innerHTML = 'HERE I AM ' + x;";
//              $pricesql = "SELECT partPrice FROM Parts WHERE partID = "document.getElementById('partNumber').value;;
                $priceresult = $pdo->query($pricesql);

echo "}
</script>";
?>
```

Comment: Read up on how to use ajax. If you need a new price for each change you would need to send data to server and return the new value

Comment: If you want to update the page without reloading it then you'll need to use JavaScript.  You can make an AJAX request to the server with the currently selected value and get back the text to show.  Or if there aren't many values then you can put them into a data structure in your JavaScript code and use that as the source of the updated text.  But either way you would write JavaScript code to respond to the `change` event for the `select` and update the label.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript allows you to update page contents dynamically without reloading the page, so if your application is static (no database) then you can use JavaScript, otherwise you have to use Ajax to send/receive data from the server using PHP as example.

so you have to read about JavaScript and Ajax to solve the problem.

best regards